# A client error occurred: Could not create storage directory: /tmp/Google_Client/00

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

What does this error mean with the Youtube API v3.0:

```
A client error occurred: Could not create storage directory: /tmp/Google_Client/00
```

I am using the PHP Youtube API on Google's documentation found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search).

Comment: When the client library can't create a storage directory, there's a problem on your server ... the permissions, perhaps, or running out of disk space, or something of that nature.

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem without changing any line of Google API.
In your php code, you juste need to specify where you want the cache folder to be:

```
$config = new Google_Config();
$config->setClassConfig('Google_Cache_File', array('directory' => '../tmp/cache'));
// Here I set a relative folder to avoid pb on permissions to a folder like /tmp that is not permitted on my mutualised host

$client = new Google_Client($config);
// And then,  you pass the config for your GoogleClient
```

It works fine for me using the Google Calendar Service.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue. I am on a shared hosting.

I was working on youtube api which was asking me to create Google_Client folder under the main \tmp on the server. Due to restriction that was not happening so I went into the

google-api-php-client/src/conifg.php and changed the following line.

```
    /***********************************Shared server therefore cannot write to server's /tmp drive therefore using an alternate location*************************************************/
    //'ioFileCache_directory'  => (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') ? sys_get_temp_dir().'/Google_Client' : '/tmp/Google_Client'),
    'ioFileCache_directory'  => 'tmp/Google_Client',
```

Then I created a tmp directory under google-api-php-client/src

Then I created a Google_Client directory under google-api-php-client/src/tmp

This worked for me. Hope this helps. If yes then mark it as answer as many folks are having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me,

at Config.php line94:

change >> 'directory' => sys_get_temp_dir() . '/Google_Client'

for >> 'directory' => '../tmp/Google_Client'

or any other dir you want

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier/better ways to do this, but i'm on my own macbook air:

i'm running xampp. I'm using the default 'htdocs' dir, '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs'.

so i:

1. went to that htdocs dir and ran "mkdir tmp; chmod 777 tmp"
2. commented out original ioFileCache_directory line and added my own:

   // IO Class dependent configuration, you only have to configure the values
   // for the class that was configured as the ioClass above

   'ioFileCache_directory'  => '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/tmp/GoogleClient',

   /* 'ioFileCache_directory'  =>
       (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') ?
           sys_get_temp_dir() . '/Google_Client' :
       '/tmp/Google_Client'), */

That's it. Don't think I had to restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your PHP code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setCache(new Google_Cache_File('/path/to/shared/cache'));
```

Comment: adding this line did not fix my issue.  but did give me a new error.  Argument 1 passed to Google_Cache_File::__construct() must be an instance of Google_Client, string given

Answer (score 0):

Are you Super-User?

```
su
password
```

and  it worked for me