# YouTube API (v3) PHP - Storage Error

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I am using Google's API for a college project to fetch YouTube Videos. I am using (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples & https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/src/Google)

However, I am receiving the following error: `An client error occurred: Could not create storage directory: /tmp/Google_Client/df`

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A client error occurred: Could not create storage directory: /tmp/Google\_Client/00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282894/a-client-error-occurred-could-not-create-storage-directory-tmp-google-client)

Comment: The lines that tells me to edit doesn't exist in mine - may be there one is outdated?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Config.php) on line 88 , you need to set path there.