# mkdir error. permission denied. google api

Tags: google-api, file-permissions, mkdir

I am attempting to use a service account with Google's API to add a calendar event using php. I have this working perfectly on a site already. When i moved it to another site on the same server, i suddenly began to receive the following error messages:

~PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in Google/Cache/File.php

~Uncaught exception 'Google_Cache_Exception' with message 'Could not create storage directory: in Google/Cache/File.php

The two environments are identical as far as i can tell
~Same server
~Same permissions on all files/folders
~Same credentials
~Both URLS authorized in Google's console

I checked with my server to see if something in the upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246114/php-mkdir-permission-denied-problem) could be the issue, but was assured that everything was set up correctly.

I've done a lot of searching and reading, but can't imagine what might be causing these errors when everything works perfectly from the other site.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes upon this: I solved this by following the advise given here:
[A client error occurred: Could not create storage directory: /tmp/Google_Client/00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282894/a-client-error-occurred-could-not-create-storage-directory-tmp-google-client)

specifically, i manually added nested folders (google and cache) inside my tmp directory and then set the path to it for google using this code (from the link above):

```
$config = new Google_Config();
$config->setClassConfig('Google_Cache_File', array('directory' => '../../tmp/google/cache'));
// Here I set a relative folder to avoid pb on permissions to a folder like /tmp that is not permitted on my mutualised host

$client = new Google_Client($config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this PHP code to your script:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setCache(new Google_Cache_File('/path/to/shared/cache'));
```

Comment: more details will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In case also that anyone needs to do this. I'm working with Codeigniter and recently moved to osx el capitan on mac from windows 7. My google cache folder had the admin permissions read and write but the error persists: mkdir permission denied, on google/cache/file.php

I looked at my code where I load the google api and added>

```
$config = new Google_Config();
$config->setClassConfig('Google_Cache_File', array('directory' => 'application/third_party/Google/src/Google/Cache/'));
$client = new Google_Client($config);
```

So with those line you set your cache folder.

Hope this helps in the future as It helped me.